# Zabbix - Some of the monitored items don't refreh

Tags: monitoring, performance-monitoring, zabbix

I'm experiencing a strange issue with Zabbix monitoring a MySQL server.

Most of the data from the server such as MySQL queries per second and MySQL uptime , Buffers memory etc. update nicely while some data like CPU iowait time (avg1) , Host local time ,MySQL number of threads and other items which were monitored in the past has last check time of about a week ago.

I can't find any logic in this, for example Mysql number of threads and Mysql queries per second are obtained in a similar way so it does not make sense one of them is monitored and one is not.

Please help- how can I fix this?

Update - I used zabbix_get from the zabbix server to check one of the items on the zabbix client and it works so the problem must be on the zabbix server side

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are some more places to look for clues...

### Item List

Go to **Configure** -> **Hosts** -> **(the host or template)** -> **Items** to get a list of items that the host is checking.  The right-most column will either be a green checkmark or a red x.  If the item in question is a red x, you can hover your mouse over it to see the error.

### Queue

Go to **Administration** -> **Queue** to see how many items are "stuck" and are not updating.  Is it just a couple or do you have a systemic problem with lots of items?

### Server Log

As someone else said, check your zabbix_server.log file.  You may also want to temporarily crank up the debug output by editing the zabbix_server.conf file.

Check those things and update your question with the findings so we can help you further.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your **zabbix_server.log** file to see what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

if some of the items are updating, and some are not, there must be some difference between them. could it be that some are zabbix passive items, and some are active items ? if so, figure out why some category has stopped working.
as you have added, querying for items is working, so maybe they have been set to be active items ? you can see that in item  properties.

if that is an accidental change, reverse it. if it's on purpose (or they have been like that always), check that :

- hostname set in agent config file matches hostname as configured in the zabbix frontend (case sensitive);
- agent host can contact zabbix server on port 10051